# take the duplicate values out of an array

Tags: php, arrays, unique

i have a text field where users can enter a string of 15 numbers only per line 50 lines max

i also need to filter out any duplicate values. so far i have this code

```
if(empty($_POST['text_field'])){$message = 'Please input values for the text_field.';}else{
    $text_field = $_POST['text_field'] ;
    $lines_unfiltered = array_slice(explode("\n", $text_field), 0, 50);
    $lines = array_unique($lines_unfiltered);
    print_r($lines);
exit;
```

but when i run it it with these numbers

```
5645646546545
2564545454544
5645646546545
```

it gives me all three lines and doesnt filter out the duplicate like it should

```
Array([0]=> 5645646546545 [1]=> 2564545454544 [2]=> 5645646546545)
```

any ideas?

Comment: You may have some extra whitespace in your strings which makes them compare as unequal. Try `array_map('trim', array_slice(explode("\n", $text_field), 0, 50))` and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: I am going to take a guess on the string length. Try using var_dump instead of print_r.

Comment: ohhhhh i see the problem, first two have \n at the end, thats why its not matching the first line with he last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as the comments have pointed out, you need to strip out the `\n`s on each string.

This could be done with:

```
trim($text_field);
```

Then you should be left with a properly formatted string that can be added to an array.

Or you could do the one-liner that the other Jon proposed:

```
$lines = array_unique(array_map('trim', array_slice(explode("\n", $text_field), 0, 50)));
```

I added the `array_unique` function around everything to ensure that the result is only unique values.